# Merge two Value files in helm

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I'm looking to merge two values files in helm.

secrets.yaml:

```yaml
oracle_db:
 serviceMonitor:
   endpoints:
     - module: oracledb
       port: http
       scheme: http
       url: "http://user:password@ip:port/xxx"
```

I have another values.yaml file which has multiple endpoints. I want to merge both the values files. I'm tried using append function to do that: `{{$endpoints := (append .Values.serviceMonitor.endpoints .Values.oracle_db.serviceMonitor.endpoints) }}` When I do a dry-run, I see its picking up both the values but won't merge. Any one come across this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a python script to merge the values files before passing them. Below is a code snippet of what I am using.

```py
import yaml
from deepmerge import always_merger

fileA = “tmp.yaml"
fileB = “feature.yaml"

with open(fileA,'r+') as f:
   fileAdictionary= yaml.load(f)

with open(fileB,'r+') as f:
   fileBdictionary = yaml.load(f)

result = always_merger.merge(fileAdictionary, fileBdictionary)
with open(‘newFile.yaml’,'w+') as f:
   yaml.dump(result,f)
```

Answer (score 9):

In the current Helm version (3) merging values is not supported.

This feature was discussed in this Github issue: [Helm should preform deep merge on multiple values files](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3486).

One important quote from there

> If this is implemented, it should be optional, i. e. the merge mode should be specified as a command-line flag. Anything else would be a breaking change and, I think, in most cases not desirable. The problem is that you would not be able to override defaults for lists.

See: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3486#issuecomment-364534501

Answer (score 2):

another option:

```
{{- define "template.valueOrDefault" -}}
{{- $value := dict -}}
{{- range (rest .) -}}
  {{- $value = merge $value . -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- if $value -}}
{{- printf "%s:" (first .) }}
{{- toYaml $value | nindent 2 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

usage:

```
 containers:
 - name: db-migrations-job
   {{- include "template.valueOrDefault" (list "resources" .Values.migrationJob.resources .Values.resources) | nindent 8 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple python script to merge values.yaml files with best effort to preserve comments, formatting, and order of items.

https://github.com/Aref-Riant/yaml-merger-py

usage:

```
python yaml-merger.py file1.yaml file2.yaml > mergedfile.yaml
```