# combining 2 yaml files to generate one values file for helm in terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, yaml, kubernetes-helm

Let us say I have 2 yaml values from 2 different files such as:

lambo.yaml:

```
    - key: car
      value: "lambo"
      descriptors:
        unit: kmh
        topspeed: 300
```

toyota.yaml:

```
    - key: car
      value: "bugatti"
      descriptors:
        unit: kmh
        topspeed: 400
```

and I want to form a yaml values file to use in a helm chart, such as:

result.yaml:

```
    domain: supercardomain
    descriptors:
      - key: supercars
        descriptors:
        - key: car
          value: "lambo"
          descriptors:
            unit: kmh
            topspeed: 300
        - key: car
          value: "bugatti"
          descriptors:
            unit: kmh
            topspeed: 400
```

CONTEXT: I have a helm_release in terraform that needs to have a ConfigMap(k8s) with the exact value as the one above(result.yaml). Merging values files in helm is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59700149/merge-two-value-files-in-helm), and we also want to avoid using any lazy hardcoded methods (such as creating `.Values.lambo` and `.Values.toyota` yaml structures and appending them to the configmap helm template).

What I have tried is:

```
car_descriptor=indent(2, format("car:\ndescriptors:\n%s\n%s", var.lambo_descriptor, var.buggati_descriptor)
```

with `var.<car>_descriptor` being a string representation of the car yaml values.

This is then used as a values file by the helm_release:

```
resource "helm_release" "my_helm_release" {
  name             = "my_helm_release"
  ...

  values = [
    var.car_descriptor
  ]
```

and then templated into the Configmap like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: car-config
data:
  config.yaml: |
    domain: supercardomain
    descriptors:
    - key: supercars
      descriptors:
{{- if .Values.car.descriptors }}
{{ toYaml .Values.car.descriptors | indent 6 }}
{{- end }}
```

It works, but I was wondering if there is a simpler and more DRY way to perform this without doing the format and indent stuff, while only using terraform/helm. Also, I would like to not mess with the yaml structure of the 2 car files, or the templating in the Configmap ([I have already tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62272109/helm-not-merging-array-of-secrets)).

Tips to make this question more concise are also greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe some combination of `yamlencode` and `join`?

Comment: I.e., `car_descriptor= join("", yamlencode(var.lambo_descriptor), yamlencode(var.buggati_descriptor))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tree

```bash
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── charts
├── data
│   ├── cars
│   │   ├── lambo.yaml
│   │   └── toyota.yaml
│   └── cpus
│       ├── amd.yaml
│       └── intel.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── NOTES.txt
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   ├── configmap.yaml
│   └── deployment.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

data/cars/lambo.yaml

```yaml
- key: car
  value: "lambo"
  descriptors:
    unit: kmh
    topspeed: 300
```

data/cars/toyota.yaml

```yaml
- key: car
  value: "bugatti"
  descriptors:
    unit: kmh
    topspeed: 400
```

data/cpus/amd.yaml

```yaml
- key: cpu
  value: "amd"
  descriptors:
    unit: cps
    topspeed: 20
```

data/cpus/intel.yaml

```yaml
- key: cpu
  value: "intel"
  descriptors:
    unit: cps
    topspeed: 10
```

template/configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  config.yaml: |
    domain: supercardomain
    descriptors:
    {{- range .Values.car.descriptors }}
      {{- $item := . }}
      - key: {{ .key }}
        descriptors:
        {{- range $path, $_ :=  $.Files.Glob  "data/**" }}
        {{- if eq (dir $path) $item.descripPath }}
        {{- $.Files.Get $path | nindent 10 }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
```

values.yaml

```yaml
car:
  domain: supercardomain
  descriptors:
    - key: supercars
      descripPath: data/cars
    - key: cpus
      descripPath: data/cpus
```

cmd

```bash
helm install test .
```

output

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  config.yaml: |
    domain: supercardomain
    descriptors:
      - key: supercars
        descriptors:
          - key: car
            value: "lambo"
            descriptors:
              unit: kmh
              topspeed: 300
          - key: car
            value: "bugatti"
            descriptors:
              unit: kmh
              topspeed: 400
      - key: cpus
        descriptors:
          - key: cpu
            value: "amd"
            descriptors:
              unit: cps
              topspeed: 20
          - key: cpu
            value: "intel"
            descriptors:
              unit: cps
              topspeed: 10
```